# a problem related to geometric progression

Tags: sequences-and-series

on the birth of a child, an aunt promises "I will deposit $100.00 in an account today and on every birthday until your 25th". Simple interest of 7.5% per annum is paid on this account. How much will be in the account after the deposit on the 25th birthday?

solution:

$S_n = a\frac{ r^n - 1}{r-1}$

$S_n = 100 \frac{1.075^{25} - 1}{1.075 - 1} =6797.79$

but answer given is $5037.50

Comment: Are you sure this is geometric progression?

Comment: I find it to be 7407.6! Are you sure about 5037.5?

Comment: perhaps answer is wrong, pls guide how to solve this question...THANKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Since the interest is not compounded, the first deposit of $\$100$ earns a total interest of
$$\$100\times7.5\% \times 25 = \$187.5$$
And the second deposit of $\$100$ earns a total interest of
$$\$100\times7.5\%\times24 = \$180$$
$$\vdots$$
The last deposit when the child is 25 years old earns a total interest of $\$0$.

Comment: Maybe, because the problem states that it's "Simple interest"? :3 And pay attention that the deposit money in the bank will grow $100 more each year (I haven't included the interest).

Comment: great,total principle deposit = $2600 and total interest = $2437.50 so total amount = $5037.50

Comment: I am using excel to derive the answer, however pls guide whether any suitable formula can be used to calculate this out??

Comment: Big hint of the day: It's an arithmetic progression. :3

Comment: yes, SIMPLE INTEREST is the interest payable only on the principal; interest that is not compounded.

Comment: d = 187.50 - 180 = 7.5
a = 100
n= 26

Sn= [2a+(n-1)d]n/2
Sn =[2*200 + 25*7.5]*26/2
Sn = 5037.50

Comment: Great guidance  BIG THANKS to your BIG HINT